# Is it possible for shareholders to get a companies assets in place of currency?

Tags: stock-market, trading

To my knowledge being a shareholder is owning a portion of a company. Then by that logic shouldn't a shareholder be able to request a companies assets instead of money? As an example, if I own 100 dollars worth of shares in XYZ company would I be able to get 100 dollars worth of their assets (chairs, tables, laptops)?

Comment: By what mechanism is a shareholder able to request money from the company to begin with? You seem to misunderstand how shareholding works. Owning 100 dollars worth of stock doesn't mean that the company will give you 100 dollars in exchange for your shares, it means *someone else* will likely buy your shares for 100 dollars. You don't usually get currency from the company, much less assets in place of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no.

Even on a liquidation scenario it’s unlikely that a common stock shareholder would be distributed physical assets.

Assuming this is a C-Corporation you are asking about, shareholders do not have rights to ‘money’ or assets held inside the company- If the shares are of a preferred class with dividend rights you may receive a portion of retained earnings.